# Google Heat Map display only one place

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I have back-end with list, where I have 2 places.

Here is code on back - end.

```
public JsonResult GetData()
    {

        List<Park> stations = new List<Park>();

        stations.Add(new Park()
        {
            Id = 2,
            GeoLat = 37.608644,
            GeoLong = 55.75226,
            Weight = 12
        });

        stations.Add(new Park()
        {
            Id = 3,
            GeoLat = 30.5807913,
            GeoLong = 50.493239,

            Weight = 12
        });

        return Json(stations.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And I get it on client side like this

```
 function getPoints() {

        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")',
            function (data) {
                var marker;
                // Проходим по всем данным и устанавливаем для них маркеры
                $.each(data,
                    function(i, item) {
                         marker = [
                            {
                                'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLong, item.GeoLat),
                                'map': map,
                                'weight': item.Weight
                            }
                        ];
                    });



                var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(marker);
                console.log(pointArray);
                heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                    data: pointArray
                });
                heatmap.setMap(map);


            });
    };
```

And update map in this method

```
 function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            {
                zoom: 13,
                center: { lat: 55.752622, lng: 37.617567 },
                mapTypeId: 'satellite'
            });
        getPoints();
    }
```

But I see only one place. I don't understood why, because I set breakpoint on this row

```
return Json(stations.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I returns 2 places.

Where can be my problem?

Thank's for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var marker;
```

should be changed to:

```
var marker = [];
```

and

```
marker = [
    {
        'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLong, item.GeoLat),
        'map': map,
        'weight': item.Weight
    }
];
```

should be changed to:

```
marker.push({
    'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLong, item.GeoLat),
    'map': map,
    'weight': item.Weight
});
```

*The problem with your existing code is that you are **assigning** to `marker` a single element array (so you will effectively only showing the last marker). You currently aren't **adding** to that array. My changes use `push` to solve this.*

Comment: Yes. It helps. Thank's